# HTML 4 Indeterminate Progress Indicator

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have an basic HTML 4 webpage with an NPAPI plugin that that I am writing which causes a Thread to run in the background and return via a JavaScript callback after several seconds.
*Don't let the "plugin" part scare you off - this is a straight forward HTML/JavaScript question.*

How can I display a simple indeterminate progress indicator during this process?
***AND***
How can I dismiss said progress dialog once I regain control in the callback?

I want this to keep this as minimal as possible.

---

**Solution**:
*I used @Brian's and @taxilian's suggestion. Here are the exact details of my implementation for the simplest possible progress indicator*.

1. I found a good animated "loading.gif" image. The right Google search
   gave a myriad of options such as this: [image: Animated Gif]
2. Add the image to your html `<body>`:
   `<img src="loading.gif" alt="Scanning..." id="loading_img" style="visibility:hidden;" />`.
3. Add JavaScript functions `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` to your `<head>` as below.
4. Call `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` at will from within other JavaScript functions to show and/or hide the animated Gif image.

**JavaScript in `<head>` Section**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLoading()
    {
        if(document.getElementById) {
            (document.getElementById("loading_img")).style.visibility="visible";
        }
    }

    function hideLoading()
    {
        if(document.getElementById) {
            (document.getElementById("loading_img")).style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just show an animated gif and then hide it again in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment above suggested, the most common way to do this is just to display an [animated gif loading indicator](https://www.google.com/search?q=loading%20indicator) and then hide it in the callback.